# asking for raw_input over and over

Tags: python

I am having an issue getting my code to print only my question.  I am able to get it to print both the question and answer, but now further.  I am sure there are more problems further down the rode, but this is where I am stuck at the moment.

```
#gives the blank spaces in the questions to the quiz
num_of_blank = ["blank1", "blank2", "blank3", "blank4"] 

#Below are the levels of questions for the quiz
easy_question = """A blank1 is something that holds a blank2, and a blank3 is a list of characters in order.  
You can also blank4 a string to a variable."""

medium_question = """An example of blank1 is an blank2 statement.  If statements can run at most blank3 time.  
Unlike the if statement, a blank4 loop can run any number of times."""

hard_question = """A blank1 is when you have a list within a list.  Lists support blank2, this means we can change the value of a list 
after it has been created.  When you have two different ways to refer to the same object that is called blank3.  In a blank4 loop, for 
each element in the list, you will assign that element to the name and evaluate the block."""

#the answers to each quiz
easy_answers = ["variable", "value", "string", "assign"]
medium_answers = ["control flow", "if", "one", "while"]
hard_answers = ["nested", "mutation", "aliasing", "for"]

#determines the level of difficulty for the questions for the user
def question_level(difficulty):
    difficulty = raw_input("Please select a level of difficulty for your questions: Easy, Medium, or Hard. ").lower()
    question, answers = question_level()
    if difficulty == "easy":
        return (easy_questions, easy_answers)
    elif difficulty == "medium":
        return (medium_question, medium_answers)
    elif difficulty == "hard":
        return (hard_question, hard_answers)
    else:
        print "That is not a level."
        question_level()
print question_level()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your function inside your function, which is a recursive call which you don't want in this case. Try checking for errors outside your function, something like:

```
def question_level():
    difficulty = raw_input("Please select a level of difficulty for your questions: Easy, Medium, or Hard. ").lower()
    if difficulty == "easy":
        return (easy_question, easy_answers)
    elif difficulty == "medium":
        return (medium_question, medium_answers)
    elif difficulty == "hard":
        return (hard_question, hard_answers)
    else:
        print "That is not a level."
        return None

q = None
while q is None:
    q = question_level()
    print(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursive call on this line

```
question, answers = question_level()
```

Just remove the question_level() part and init answers to something else.